# Class names via CSS modules are generated in a strange way

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, sass

I configured `CSS-modules` via `webpack`, but as a result, the class names look wrong.

It feels like webpack is not responding to them. Although it should look something like this:
`class="Input-input_ytoew"` but you can see the result yourself.

```
webpack
----------
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.s?css$/,
        use: [
          "style-loader",
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
              importLoaders: 1,
              modules: true,
            },
          },
        ],
        include: /\.module\.scss$/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.s?css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
        exclude: /\.module\.scss$/,
      },
    ],
  },
};


Input.stx
----------
import React from "react";

import s from "./Input.module.scss";

export const Input = ({ value }: any) => {
  return (
    <>
      <input className={s.input} type="text" value={value} />
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [`localIdentName` of `css-loader`](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/#localidentname). The property is responsible for generating the class names.

I'd usually go with:

```js
{
    loader: 'css-loader',
    options: {
        modules: {
            localIdentName:'[name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]',
        },
    },
},
```

Comment: Tnx) 
Do you know, how can i exclude part *.`module`.* in class name  `Input-module__input--yBU80` ?

Comment: @MichaelPodlevskykh It's there because your CSS file name is `*.module.css`, right? Unfortunately, the `[name]` variables uses the full file name

Comment: @ItayGanorI I found some project and there I saw this details on screenshot. Maybe this possible
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxO1F.png) 
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJRD3.png)

Comment: @MichaelPodlevskykh Share the link, I'll investigate

Comment: @ItayGanorI [link](https://github.com/mishapodl/digital)

Comment: @MichaelPodlevskykh They use a custom `localIdentName` option that replaces occurrences of `'.module'` with `''`. See [the implementation](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/main/packages/react-dev-utils/getCSSModuleLocalIdent.js)

Comment: @ItayGanorI Is it something like this? [link](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/#getlocalident)

Answer (score 1):

Solution

```
     {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader',
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: {
                localIdentName: '[local]--[hash:base64:5]',
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
```